# a question of subsets of the complete graph with 10 vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Imagine 10 guests, each must meet each other once and only once. there are 5 rooms in which they can meet. clearly there are 45 required meetings. 5 meetings must occur at every 10 minutes, so in total, each guest will spend 90 minutes meeting the other guests.

Is it possible to come up with some sort of schematic to allow each guest to meet every other guest once, every guest must be in a meeting at all times (10 mins exactly for each meeting).

I think this is the same as considering the complete graph with 10 vertices, what are the subsets that have only 5 edges, so that each one of the 45 edges belongs to one and only one of the subsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this question correctly you are searching for a decomposition of the complete graph $K_{10}$ into perfect matchings. See for example
[this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78385/decomposition-of-a-complete-graph-into-maximal-matching-subgraphs).

Answer (score 0):

For even $n=2k$, there is a nice way to get it:
Draw a regular $n-gon$, and decompose the diagonals into parallel lines.
Take the $k$ lines that are parallel, and this forms a meeting.

For odd $n=2k+1$, there is a similarly nice way to get it, where 1 person sits out each time.
Can you find this?